# AngularJS directive copying with getElementById(myID).innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to copy/display the content of one div (which contains directives) into another. 
When I execute the below the directives show up fine but none of the functionality, e.g. ng-click, work.

**The ng-click and other options work in the source Div just not when it is copied into the destination.**

Also I am not getting any console errors.

Please advise.

```
var srcDiv = document.getElementById(id + '-content'); //contains directives + all working fine
var dstDiv = document.getElementById(id + 'x'); //contains directives but no functionality or errors

dstDiv.innerHTML = srcDiv.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Angular to $compile the contents. Angular will not recognise bits of HTML being inserted into the DOM at arbitrary times.

Inject the `$compile` service to wherever you are doing your DOM manipulation.

```
var srcDiv = angular.element(document.getElementById(id + '-content'));
var dstDiv = angular.element(document.getElementById(id + 'x'));

dstDiv.html(srcDiv.html());

$compile(dstDiv)(scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
...
dstDiv.innerHTML = srcDiv.innerHTML;
scope.$apply();
```